# Redux search in React-Native

Tags: react-native, redux, full-text-search

[This](https://github.com/bvaughn/redux-search) is a good Lib for adding client side search for Web using Redux as Store. However Its not really built for react-native because it uses Web-workers.

The data is just an array with ~500 entries. I am currently using `filter()` js function but is there a more efficient option. I did think about using a full text service like algolia but it seems since data can be fetched in entirety before search it actually will be slower.